# SQL multiple column ordering

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by, multiple-columns

How can I sort multiple columns in SQL and in different directions? For instance,  'column1' would be sorted descendingly and 'column2' ascendingly.

Answer (score 1439, accepted):

```
ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2
```

This sorts everything by `column1` (descending) first, and then by `column2` (ascending, which is the default) whenever the `column1` fields for two or more rows are equal.

Comment: here how to order either column1 or column2?

Comment: @PoliDev, It first orders by column1 in DESCending order and the by column2 (in ASCending order)

Comment: For clarity, this sorts everything by `column1` first and then by `column2` whenever the `column1` fields for two rows are equal.

Comment: I assume that this will work for additional columns also?

Comment: It will work for any number of expressions (*not* just columns), up to your RDBMS's limit.

Comment: @NickBenes ...or you could say: it sorts by `column2` and then performs STABLE sorting by `column1`. This is more clear for people that knows what stable sorting is.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The result remains the same I mean it only order by first column not after that.

Comment: say i am having a result set with three columns in it. I wish to have first column in my result set in DESC, Second Column in result Set in ASC and third column in result set in DESC. How will i do it?

Comment: @DeepakKeynas Put desc after the third one, asc can be ommited because it's the default, he could also put asc after column2.

Comment: what is the opposite of this? column 1, column2 DESC?

Answer (score 500):

The other answers lack a concrete example, so here it goes:

Given the following **People** table:

```
 FirstName |  LastName   |  YearOfBirth
----------------------------------------
  Thomas   | Alva Edison |   1847
  Benjamin | Franklin    |   1706
  Thomas   | More        |   1478
  Thomas   | Jefferson   |   1826
```

If you execute the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY FirstName DESC, YearOfBirth ASC
```

The result set will look like this:

```
 FirstName |  LastName   |  YearOfBirth
----------------------------------------
  Thomas   | More        |   1478
  Thomas   | Jefferson   |   1826
  Thomas   | Alva Edison |   1847
  Benjamin | Franklin    |   1706
```

Comment: This answer is a great supplement to the very helpful and short accepted answer.

Comment: The is some good example, many think that how can you sort 2 columns at single time which actually does not happen even if you put 2 columns for order query

Comment: It's providing same results when we sort with three columns and first column sorting order is same and rest everything is differ. Ex:  : ```1.Firstname asc, Lastname desc, yearOfBirst asc  and 2.Firstname asc, Lastname desc, yearOfBirst desc```

Is there any way we can overcome this?

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti: That's the expected outcome. The resulting ordering in your example would only differ if there were duplicate `FirstName, LastName` entries with distinct `YearOfBirth`

Answer (score 149):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        column1 DESC, column2 ASC
```

Answer (score 26):

Multiple column ordering depends on both column's corresponding values:
Here is my table example where are two columns named with Alphabets and Numbers and the values in these two columns are *asc* and *desc* orders.

[image]

Now I perform **Order By** in these two columns by executing below command:

[image]

Now again I insert new values in these two columns, where Alphabet value in *ASC* order:

[image]

and the columns in Example table look like this.
Now again perform the same operation:

[image]

You can see the values in the first column are in desc order but second column is not in ASC order.

Comment: also insert this data too `(g, 10),(g,12)`. Then, run your order-by query, you get second column as `ASC` order(that means `g-10,g-11,g-12)`

Answer (score 13):

You can use multiple ordering on multiple condition,

```
ORDER BY 
     (CASE 
        WHEN @AlphabetBy = 2  THEN [Drug Name]
      END) ASC,
    CASE 
        WHEN @TopBy = 1  THEN [Rx Count]
        WHEN @TopBy = 2  THEN [Cost]
        WHEN @TopBy = 3  THEN [Revenue]
    END DESC
```

Comment: Does indexing work, If I use "CASE" inside "ORDER BY"?

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT id,  
  first_name,
  last_name,
  salary
FROM employee
ORDER BY salary DESC, last_name;
```

If you want to select records from a table but would like to see them sorted according to two columns, you can do so with ORDER BY. This clause comes at the end of your SQL query.

After the ORDER BY keyword, add the name of the column by which you’d like to sort records first (in our example, salary). Then, after a comma, add the second column (in our example, last_name). You can modify the sorting order (ascending or descending) separately for each column. If you want to use ascending (low to high) order, you can use the ASC keyword; this keyword is optional, though, as that is the default order when none is specified. If you want to use descending order, put the DESC keyword after the appropriate column (in the example, we used descending order for the salary column).

Answer (score 6):

TRY

```
'select * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC, name ASC, age DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: Compiled through Intellij DataGrip]

SELECT * FROM EMP **ORDER BY DEPTNO ASC, JOB DESC**;

Answer (score 2):

You can also sort or order by the **Number of Characters** in each Column you wish to sort by. Shown below is a sample which sorts by the **first three characters** of the First Name and by the **last two characters** in the name of the town.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY LEFT(FirstName, 3) ASC, LEFT(Town, 2);
```

Comment: note that you'd need to specifically create indexes for those cases as a normal index on `FirstName` and `Town` wouldn't be used because of obfuscation more at https://planetscale.com/courses/mysql-for-developers/queries/index-obfuscation