# SQL Order By clause with group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

So I have a SELECT query, and the result is like this:

```
SELECT .... 
ORDER BY SCORE, STUDENT_NUMBER

STUDENT_NAME    STUDENT_NUMBER    SCORE     
----------------------------------------
  Adam              9              69
  Bob              20              76
  Chris            10              77
  Dave             14              77
  Steve             5              80
  Mike             12              80
```

But I want to order by STUDENT_NUMBER, but I want them to be grouped by the same score:

```
STUDENT_NAME    STUDENT_NUMBER    SCORE     
----------------------------------------
  Steve             5              80
  Mike             12              80
  Adam              9              69
  Chris            10              77
  Dave             14              77
  Bob              20              76
```

So now the data is ordered by STUDENT_NUMBER, but if there is the same SCORE, they are grouped (like it is shown in the next row).

Is it possible to do this with the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: You guys can't read?

Comment: Please understand OP question first b4 answering/commenting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the ordering can also be described as ordering by the minimum student number for each score.  You would do this using window functions.  Here is an example:

```
select <whatever>
from (select t.*, min(student_number) over (partition by score) as minsn
      from <whatever> t
     ) t
order by minsn, score, student_number asc;
```

You do ask if this can be done with the `order by`.  I think the answer is "yes", using a subquery.  It would look something like this:

```
select <whatever>
from <whatever> t
order by (select min(t2.student_number)
          from <whatever> t2
          where t2.score = t.score
         ),
         score, student_number;
```

Comment: The second answer is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could order by the minimum student number with that score, then by student number:

```
SELECT STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_NUMBER, SCORE 
FROM Scores s
ORDER BY (SELECT(MIN(STUDENT_NUMBER) FROM Scores WHERE SCORE = s.SCORE) ,
         STUDENT_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves your curious ordering requirement. Instead of ordering on Student_Number, you order on the minimum Student_Number for a given score.

```
WITH v AS
(
    SELECT t1.Student_Number, t1.Score,
    (
        SELECT MIN(Student_Number) FROM table1
        WHERE Score = t1.Score
    ) AS MinStudentNumber
    FROM table1 t1
)
SELECT Student_Number, Score FROM v
ORDER BY MinStudentNumber, Score
```