# Order rows by other column value if value in different rows is same mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've sorted a mySQL table by total. But it can happen that some rows have the same value. If the rows have the same value I want to sort them by another row. Is this possible?

```
ID | pos | name | m1 | m2 | total
1  | 1   | mike | 1  | 1  | 50
2  | 2   | alex | 16 | 12 | 14
3  | 3   | joe  | 25 | 7  | 14 
4  | 4   | jani | 7  | 24 | 14
```

The table is sorted by total, but if total is the same I want to sort the rows with the same value by the m2 column and change the pos by that order.

Comment: umm, aren't you looking for `ORDER BY total DESC, m2 DESC`

Comment: This is such an easy to research question.  It should have never been asked.  There are many questions like this already asked: [**SQL multiple column ordering**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible - you can give several columns in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY total DESC, m2 DESC
```