# ORDERING mysqli/PHP, how to add more ordering by?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, sql-order-by

May be stupid question, but I'm not sure how to extend this code to order for example by published name, by size, by name and etc, just make more ordering buttons.

This is code:

```
$query ="SELECT newsvid.id, newsvid.addName, newsvid.vidTitle, newsvid.url, newsvid.vidSD, newsvid.published, videoinformation.vidLD, videoinformation.vidYear, videoinformation.vidCity, videoinformation.vidZanr, videoinformation.vidZanr2, videoinformation.vidZanr3, videoinformation.vidQuality, videoinformation.vidTranslated, videoinformation.vidTime  FROM newsvid, videoinformation WHERE newsvid.id = videoinformation.id";
$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : 'ASC';
$goodParam = array("ASC", "DESC");

if (in_array($order, $goodParam)) {
if($order == 'ASC'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC"; 
}else{
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC"; 
    }
}
```

And this is my buttons:

```
<a href="view.php?order=ASC">ASC</a> 
<a href="view.php?order=DESC">DESC</a>
```

P.S. I use samples from internet and adopt to my website and now can't extended, not sure how. 
Thank you
What exactly I need to change in php code to use this links?

```
<a href="view.php?order=ASC">ASC</a> 
<a href="view.php?order=name">BY Name</a>
<a href="view.php?order=year">By Year</a>
<a href="view.php?order=published">By Publishing</a>
<a href="view.php?order=size">By Size</a>
```

DO I have to using like this??

```
if (in_array($order, $goodParam)) {
if($order == 'ASC'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC"; 
}else if{
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.vidTitle DESC"; 
}else if{
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.published DESC"; 
}else{
     $query .= " ORDER BY videoinformation.vidZard DESC"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: why is `$order == 'ASC'` and then appending `ORDER BY newsvid.id DESC`?

Comment: This is what sample was, and it's work correctly.

Comment: @Ghost code corrected...

Comment: just do it just the same as you would concatenate. just one thing to point out just as you whitelist `ASC, and desc` you also need that to filter columns since you can't bind them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more than one `ORDER BY` like that:

```
ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC, newsvid.addName DESC
```

That sort first the ID and with 2 equal ID the Name.

If you just try to add new sort, you just can change the name in your `ORDER BY`...

You can do:

```
if($order == 'ASC'){
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.id ASC"; 
} elseif ($order == 'name') {
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.addName ASC"; 
} elseif ($order == 'year') {
     $query .= " ORDER BY newsvid.vidYear ASC"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on general SQL. `ORDER BY` can take multiple arguments, like `ORDER BY id, date_created, upvotecount`.

Also: [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)