# Ordering results by values in other table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I have two tables :

```
               Table1

    id  |  name  |  age |  d_o_b  
=====================================
    1   |  ASD   |  22  |  12/01/1992  
    2   |  QWE   |  21  |  04/04/1993  
    3   |  FRG   |  24  |  04/04/1990


   Table2

    id  |  age
===============
    1   |  22  
    2   |  21
    3   |  24
```

Is it possible to order by two columns one from first Table1 and then by one column from Table2.

Something like ..

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 order by d_o_b , age in (SELECT * FROM Table2)
```

Comment: Not sure whats your problem but you have age in table1 why don't you use that in order by

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: you need join two tables then you can order by

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  `d_o_b` is unique in the first table, so an additional `order by` key is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

To order by a column in other table you may need to join them. This should work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM Table1 a
join table2 b
on a.id=b.id
order by d_o_b,b.age
```

Comment: This does provide the answer to the question.

Comment: `order by age` gives the result in ascending order of age.....but what I need is the result in the order of age which is present in `Table2`

Comment: that's why the order clause is "b.age"  , b is table2 alias so b.age is the age in table2