# How to order by Asc its my query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="SELECT SALUTATION,NAME FROM ownership_profile WHERE SID='".$_SESSION['socityid']."' and UNIT_ID='".$unit."'";
```

How to ordery By ASC, 1st have to come Id with by acending order and second Names by Ascending Order.

Comment: RTM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: `order by id, names`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example this is working fine for me,

I think this is a exact answer for your requirement.

Code:-

```
<?php
  require_once("connect.php");

    $sql="SELECT SALUTATION,NAME FROM ownership_profile WHERE    SID='".$_SESSION['socityid']."' and UNIT_ID='".$unit."' order by NAME asc  ";

    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row['NAME'];

    }
    }
    echo "After Sorting".'<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>'; 
?>
```

sample output

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => bca
    [2] => cad
    [3] => efg
    [4] => fgh
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving us much to work with. What is your table structure? I'm only guessing column names with the below.

```
$sql="SELECT SALUTATION,NAME FROM ownership_profile WHERE SID='".$_SESSION['socityid']."' and UNIT_ID='".$unit."' ORDER BY Id ASC, SecondName ASC";
```

Besides, a quick trip to Google/SO reveals this:
[SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: You're still not giving me enough information to help you. Please look into it yourself and try to fix it.

Comment: this is my code ___>                                                                                                   function getPreUnitOwner($unit)

{

 $sql="SELECT SALUTATION,NAME FROM ownership_profile WHERE SID='".$_SESSION['socityid']."' and UNIT_ID='".$unit."'";

 $result = mysql_query ($sql);

 $fullname="";

 while ($result && $a = mysql_fetch_row ($result)){

  $sal=$a[0];

  $name=$a[1];

  $fullname=$sal.' '.$name;

 }

 return $fullname;

}

Answer (score 0):

```
order by id asc,
         name asc
```