# Sorting the Data based on same set of columns

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have two columns named country and country1 in the same table which are having same datatype and data stored also same i.e., India and United_states, but country has 40 rows of data which is combination of India and United_states and country1 has 60 rows. I need to sort the data based on India and United_states separately. So can any1 help me in this? when i am trying to sort the data either country1 gets sorted or country gets sorted but not both using MySQL.

```
#Name#  #country#           #country1#
  A      India               United states
  B      United states       United states
  C      India               United states
  D      India               India
  E                          India
```

i need something like dis

## Name#   #country#     #country1

A        India
C        India
D        India          India
E                       India

Comment: Are you talking about sorting in SQL? If yes which DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) are you using? And how do your tables look like?

Comment: Columns? On a sheet of paper?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering

Comment: ya but dat is not helping

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE country = 'India' AND country1 = India ORDER BY country DESC, country1 DESC
```

Comment: i tried it but wat i want is the data for a particular country not both at the same time

Comment: SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE country = 'India' ORDER BY country DESC, country1 DESC

Comment: When i am trying dis query i ll get country as India but country1 will have both Unitedstates and India

Comment: it is not working and if i create another table will it work?