# Can we perform order by on more than 2 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, sql-order-by

Bit confused if we can perform order by on more than two columns.

Here is the result:-

```
Select * 
from orderbytest 
order by FName desc, LName desc, YearOfBirth desc
```

Resulting output:

```
FName     LName         YearOfBirth
------------------------------------
Thomas    More          1478
Thomas    Jefferson     1826
Thomas    Alva Edison   1847
Benjamin  White         1600
Benjamin  Franklin      1706
```

Comment: yes we can it will work as priority of order

Comment: Ok so why are you confused?The results would be easier to understand if you had duplicates in the LName column also.

Comment: Don't be confused. Keep calm and try understand code. See good:)

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes.

When applying multiple `order by` expressions the results are sorted by the first one. When multiple rows have the same value in the first order by expression, they are sorted internally by the second one. When multiple rows have the same value in the first and second order by expressions they are sorted by the third one, and so on.

Here, all your rows have a unique combination of the first two expressions, so the third one, while still valid, is inconsequential.

Comment: I guess i understood it.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can perform however you like Just like Grouping.

here;

```
Select * from orderbytest order by FName ,LName asc,YearOfBirth desc
```

Not that, when you do not write any keyword after a field the result will list in the default order.

Comment: Just to be clear: default sort order is **asc** - so this sorts by FName **asc**, LName **asc** and only by YearOfBirth **desc** - not like what the OP has in his question.

Comment: Yes sir I missed something  and I edited the post. Thank you for warning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  try this query for understanding order by more then one column:

```
select *
from
(
    select 'ashish' col1,1 col2
    union all
    select 'ashish',3
)base
order by col1 asc, col2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This will group in Descending order of  FName , LName , YearOfBirth

```
SELECT        FName, LName, YearOfBirth
FROM            orderbytest
ORDER BY FName DESC, LName DESC, YearOfBirth DESC
```

For ascending order :

```
SELECT        FName, LName, YearOfBirth
FROM            orderbytest
ORDER BY FName , LName , YearOfBirth
```