# Calculate user rank based on two columns

Tags: php, mysql

I did wrote a Web Service for a Android game with PHP. The query is used for calculating user's rank is like this:

```
$rank = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT FIND_IN_SET(`score`, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`score` ORDER BY `score` DESC) FROM `scores`)) AS `rank` FROM `scores` WHERE `user_id` =  '{$user_id}'"));
```

So, what is the problem? Suppose `user_a` submit his score (for example 1000) and `$rank` equals to 1, then if `user_b` submit the same score as `user_a`, the `$rank` will be 1 again. I don't want this, in the case of score equality, first user must have the higher rank. So I added a new integer column for `submit_date` timestamp to `scores` table and tried to manipulate the query and unfortunately since i'm not professional in SQL, My efforts failed.

Update: I won't store the rank itself in the database. The `scores` table structure looks like this:

```
`_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`score` int(11) NOT NULL,
`submit_date` int(11) NOT NULL
```

The `user_id` is unique. If a user didn't submitted his score before, a new record created. Else his record will be updated (in case new score is higher than old one).

What should i do?

Comment: maybe add ordering by submit date in multiple order with score http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering

Comment: @pmaniora Thanks for your comment. I tried this before: GROUP_CONCAT(`score` ORDER BY `score` DESC, `submit_date`), did not worked.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT doesn't group by score? then its flatten to 1 maybe try SELECT `score` ?

Comment: @pmaniora I tried this: "SELECT FIND_IN_SET(score, (SELECT score ORDER BY score DESC, submit_date FROM scores)) AS rank FROM scores WHERE user_id =  '{$user_id}'". Did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    If two user with same score and do display old user at top.
    you can add on update date ie when the score is update the current date time will be inserted on that field.
    then when you invoke record from the data base retrieve according to rank and update date
    like: 
    SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY rank DESC, update_date ASC

from this you can get two field can order at a time
```

[image: table for above result]