# mysql order by field equivalent in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

How do I accomplish this custom sort by field feature available in MySQL in hibernate?

```
select * from pet order by field(species, 'cat', 'dog', 'bird');
```

For some business reason, I need to enforce a custom ordering.

PS -I am new to hibernate.

Comment: Not sure if we have something same in hibernate but below links describes all types of sort in hibernate http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an HQL like this

```
commaDelimitedSpecies = "'cat', 'dog', 'bird'";
orderBySpecies = " ORDER BY FIELD(species, " + commaDelimitedSpecies + ")  DESC";
Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM PetModel pet" + orderBySpecies);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Spring HibernateDAO:

```
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParametersQuery(
"FROM MyEntity me WHERE me.id IN :ids ORDER BY FIELD(id, :ids)", new String[] {"ids"}, new Object[] {uuidList.toArray()},uuidList.size()
);
```

Note: getHibernateTemplate returns an instance of *org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate*