# Order by a first column and then order by a second one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
Age | Points
-------
22  | 5000   
15  | 100
22  | 45
14  | 50
13  | 10
12  | 500
11  | 356
15  | 25
```

And I like a result like this (first I order table by age and then for each age I order by points):

```
Age | Points
-------
22  | 5000 
22  | 45
15  | 100
15  | 25
14  | 50
13  | 10
12  | 500
11  | 356
```

How can I do it through SQL?

Comment: Dupicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
order by age desc, points desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from TableName
order by Age desc, Points desc
```

Comment: I solved it. I wrote "Points desc, Age desc" that's why I didn't get the expected result

Comment: @kirito100floors You didn't write anything

Answer (score 0):

use order by clause

```
select * from TABLE 
order by age ,points desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from TableName
order by Age desc, Points desc
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered poor-quality content on Stack Overflow. Please provide information about why this answers the question.  Copying another answer verbatim is considered very poor form, and without any kind of commentary, this looks very bad.