# Sort data from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table named `camp_details` which has the following columns :

```
camp_id, camp_name, location, category, months , pattern
```

I have input fields which accepts values for `location`, `category`, `months` and `pattern`.

Based on the details provided, the table should sort according to the preferences (1:`location` , 2:`Months` , 3:`pattern` and 4:`category`).

That is, the table should display first containing `location`, next `months` and so on.

Kindly help me out in this.

Comment: What is the question? You can have multiple ORDER BY fields in SQL

Comment: What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on? Also, what are you using, mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understood your question, but here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this `query`

```
SELECT * FROM camp_details ORDER BY location , months,patter,category ;
```

or use `DESC` after column name which you want to sort in `desc` like

```
SELECT * FROM camp_details ORDER BY location , months DESC,patter,category ;
```

Comment: but location, months, pattern, category  will be given by form fields and that how can i pass in order by query ?

Comment: This query is for display the table value what you exactly want please update your question i just though that you want to display a database table

Comment: Thank You ..Query Working Fine I passed the values in the query