# MySQL - Select all rows which not exist or a field equal to value

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables:

**g1 :**

```
id |  name  | 
1  |  G1    |
2  |  G2    |
3  |  G3    |
4  |  G4    | 
5  |  G5    |
```

**g_u_groups :**

```
id | group_id | action |
1  |    2     |  view  |
2  |    3     |  add   |
3  |    2     |  view  |
4  |    3     |  view  |
5  |    1     |  add   |
```

I have a problem with the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM g1 
LEFT JOIN g_u_groups ON
    g_u_groups.group_id = g1.id 
    AND (g_u_groups.action = 'add' OR g_u_groups.id is null) 
ORDER BY g_u_groups.id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Now it selects only the groups which have rows in `g_u_groups`.

I want to order all groups by latest `'add'` action but I also want to select the `groups` which don't have `actions`.

The expected results :

```
id |  name  | 
1  |  G1    |
3  |  G3    |
2  |  G2    |
4  |  G4    | 
5  |  G5    |
```

Comment: Elaborate your question with sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Viki888 here you go

Comment: add the expected  result please

Comment: Kindly provide the sample data for your scenario. You have said as **I also want to select the groups which don't have actions**. I cannot see this scenario in your sample. Also provide the **expected result**.

Comment: @Viki888 what about now

Comment: @AhmedDousa On seeing your expected result, I will suggest `SELECT * FROM g1`. Will this solve your problem? If not kindly provide proper expected data.

Comment: @Viki888 i want to order the results by the latest actions in another table please check the expected results above

Answer (score 0):

Does this return the expected?

```
    SELECT g1.id, g1.name
    FROM g1 
    LEFT JOIN g_u_groups 
     ON g_u_groups.group_id = g1.id 
      AND g_u_groups.action = 'add' or g_u_groups.id is null 
    ORDER BY g_u_groups.id DESC, g1.id DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering) talk about sorting multiple columns, it could help you

Comment: same issue, but if i removed the where condition i will receive all the results my only problem will be the order of the groups.

Comment: edited my post, check the link for multiple column sorting in my post

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL returning by latest add action also showing items without action:

```
SELECT * 
FROM g1 
LEFT JOIN g_u_groups ON
g_u_groups.group_id = g1.id 
where (g_u_groups.action = 'add' OR g_u_groups.id is null) 
ORDER BY g_u_groups.id DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```