# How can I build a query to retrieve ordered list without using orderBy twice?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example if I take a simple SQL query:

```
Select user WHERE name = jack ORDER BY date_added ASC
```

The firebase Query to retreive all users with name jack will look like:

```
myRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("jack")
```

but if I add

```
myRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo("jack").orderByChild("date_added")
```

I will get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!
```

so how can I order by ASC and DESC after using orderBy and equalto?

Comment: I don't know how firebase works, but in plain sql you can order by two columns just putting then together in the order clause, but separated by comma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering

Answer (score 4):

you can't use `orderByChild` more than one time.
i ran into this problem and i ended up by using  `orderByChild` once and filter the data on my client .
you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/2968988) answer , it will help you

Comment: how can i achieve result?

Comment: use orderByChild  and then filter the rest of the data on your client side