# How to sum the records of Varchar2 and Null Values?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I have same dates but with different Invoice_no_pawl varchar2 and Null. How to show the 1200.00 in the first place and of the date?

This is the query:

```
select invoice_date, invoice_no_pwal, invoice_value, payment_rec
from partywise_accounts_ledger
where name_of_the_customer = 'Naresh Agencies'
```

[image]

Comment: Just simply group by the date field...

Comment: School homework?

Comment: Is varchar2 really a MySQL type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2
```

This sorts everything by column1 (descending) first, and then by column2 (ascending, which is the default) whenever the column1 fields for two rows are equal.

Best of luck!

Reference: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2051176/4210935)