# How do I order two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

My output to the question was this:-

```
FIRSTNAME  COURSENAME
---------- --------------------
Anand      C++
Bala       C++
Dileep     Linux and C
Gowri      Java
Gowri      Linux and C
Gowri      C#
John       C++
John       Oracle
Prem       Linux and C
Priya      Java
Priya      Oracle
Priya      C#
Rahul      Oracle
```

But the expected output is:-

```
FIRSTNAME  COURSENAME
---------- --------------------
Anand      C++
Bala       C++
Dileep     Linux and C
Gowri      C#
Gowri      Java
Gowri      Linux and C
John       C++
John       Oracle
Prem       Linux and C
Priya      C#
Priya      Java
Priya      Oracle
Rahul      Oracle
```

My code:

```
select firstname, coursename
from course
inner join
    (select student.firstname as firstname, registration.courseid
     from student
     inner join registration on student.studid = registration.studid
     group by student.firstname, registration.courseid) q1 on q1.courseid = course.courseid
order by firstname asc;
```

How do I arrange two columns in ascending order keeping the other fixed? (maybe I didn't sound good in explaining this)

Comment: Do you want to order by the column firstname then coursename?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Answer (score 6):

```
order by firstname, coursename
```

Or

```
order by firstname asc, coursename asc
```

Comment: This is the expected resultset. How you conclude the Gowri & Priya coursename ordering ?

Comment: Arun answer is correct because Alphabetically J comes before L