# how to order my sql value in desc

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Distinct ', '+ (select text from dbo.codelists 
where id = LoadReferenceTypeId), ': ' +  ReferenceValue FROM dbo.LoadReferences 
WHERE LoadId = 89 and EndDate IS NULL
```

Comment: looks like `sql-server`. Please remove unwanted tags. And be clear on what you are trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: You should read about joins and use them instead of subqueries in your columns. Then use some aliases so you know which table each column came from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `order by` at the end of SQL statement.

Try:

```
SELECT Distinct ', '+ 
(
  select text from dbo.codelists 
  WHERE id = LoadReferenceTypeId
)
, ': ' +  ReferenceValue 
FROM dbo.LoadReferences 
WHERE LoadId = 89 and EndDate IS NULL
ORDER BY column_name DESC;
```