# Conditional Group By sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to sort database query by:

number value DESCENDING considering String property from another field

Something like:

```
ORDER BY money DESC,
currency = 'EUR'
```

Example:

```
money    |     currency
-----------------------
200      |     EUR
300      |     USD
500      |     USD
100      |     EUR
400      |     EUR
```

I would like to sort `money` in descending fashion only when `currency` is equal to `EUR`. I don't want other currency to be considered in sorting such as:

```
money    |     currency
-----------------------
400      |     EUR
200      |     EUR
100      |     EUR
300      |     USD
500      |     USD
```

I don't need the sorting after `EUR`. Could be totally random

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple keys in the `order by`:

```
order by (currency = 'EUR') desc,
         money desc
```

This orders the remaining currencies in descending order.  That is a by-product.  If you specifically want them to be random:

```
order by (currency = 'EUR') desc,
         (case when currency = 'EUR' then money end) desc,
         rand()
```

But that seems like overkill.

Comment: ill test it and get back to you with answer

Comment: works as  a charm. I need to translate it to queryDSL somehow, seems to be tricky

Answer (score 1):

If you really want an order condition only on 'EUR' value you can do something like this :

```
 ORDER BY (currency = 'EUR') * money DESC
```