# Order by max value in group

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have this

```
Name   | Team     | Value
-------|----------|--------
A      | RED      |1
B      | BLUE     |2
C      | RED      |3
D      | BLUE     |4
E      | BLUE     |5
```

i need this:
 Team with higher max value showed first

```
Name   | Team     | Value
-------|----------|--------
B      | BLUE     |2
D      | BLUE     |4
E      | BLUE     |5
A      | RED      |1
C      | RED      |3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, find "Rank" (maximum Value) for each `Team` group in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) `t2`.
- **Join** this derived table with your table based using `Team`.
- Now, sort the results by "Rank" in descending order, and `Name` in Ascending order. So that the rows of the Team with highest maximum value come first, sorted by their `Name` within themselves.

You can try the following query (replace `your_table` with your actual table name):

```
SELECT t1.Name, 
       t1.Team, 
       t1.Value 
FROM your_table AS t1 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT t2.Team, 
         MAX(t2.Value) AS rank 
  FROM your_table AS t2 
  GROUP BY t2.Team 
) AS t2 ON t2.Team = t1.Team 
ORDER BY t2.rank DESC, t1.Name ASC
```