# How to do multilevel Ordering in mat table in angular

Tags: sql, angular

I have table `customer` with columns `country`, `customer_id` and `customer_name`.

I need to order the mat table in angular by columns `country`, `customer_id` and `customer_name`, like in SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY country, Customer-Name;
```

Comment: Provide your column name in the order which you want separated by a comma after ORDER BY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: I'm confused. Is this an SQL question or an Angular question?

Comment: This is an angular question

Comment: I got output sorry for wasting your valuable times thank u so much for all.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uxibic/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @Ajai - Please post the answer and mark it accepted, if you were able to figure it out. That might help someone in future :)