# Filter by Last AND First Name in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with last and first names in separate columns. I need to return all rows containing duplicate last and first names. I have this so far and it works to filter by last name only but not sure how to filter by the first name too. Would appreciate some guidance.
Thanks!

```
with cte1 as (
  select 
    distinct lastName as last_name,
    count(lastName) over (partition by lastName) as ln_count
  from peoplelist
),

cte2 as (
  select 
    ng.*
    from
     peoplelist ng
    left join 
      cte1 on cte1.last_name = ng.LastName
    where cte1.ln_count > 1
    order by LastName desc
)
select * from cte2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

You could concat the names together and just perform a count by full name and add the full name with a group by and having > 1

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LastName) AS FULLNAME
, COUNT(CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LastName)) AS FULLNAMECOUNT
FROM
PEOPLELIST
GROUP BY CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LastName)
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LastName)) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_name
      ,last_name
from   (
       select *
            ,row_number() over(partition by first_name,last_name order by first_name) as rn
       from t
       ) t
where  rn > 1
```

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| Alma | Slor |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MQEXF656)