# Sort SQL by value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like this:

| Customer ID | Name | Type | Last Submit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Patricio | C | January 2022 |
| 2 | Dale | A | June 2022 |
| 3 | Yvonne | C | July 2022 |
| 4 | Pawe | C | JUne 2022 |
| 5 | Sergio | B | August 2022 |
| 6 | Roland | C | August 2022 |
| 7 | Georg | D | November 2022 |
| 8 | Catherine | D | October 2022 |
| 9 | Pascale | E | October 2022 |
| 10 | Irene | A | November 2022 |

How to sort type A out of the queue first like A,B,C,D,E,F, then the last submit is at the top.

The example output:

| Customer ID | Name | Type | Last Submit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Irene | A | November 202[![enter image description here][1]][1]2 |
| 1 | Dale | A | June 2022 |
| 5 | Sergio | B | August 2022 |
| 6 | Roland | C | August 2022 |
| 3 | Yvonne | C | July 2022 |
| 4 | Pawe | C | June 2022 |
| 1 | Patricio | C | January 2022 |
| 7 | Georg | D | November 2022 |
| 8 | Catherine | D | October 2022 |
| 9 | Pascale | E | October 2022 |

Comment: What data type is column `Last submit` - if this is actually a *date* it should not be a *string*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to sort by 2 different columns, this is detailed in this other answer: [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

In your example you would do

```
ORDER BY type, last_submit
```

Comment: Note that last_submit doesn't work when month names aren't in alphabetical order.

Comment: good catch @jarlh ! I assumed that the column would be a timestamp

Comment: how about sorting like b, c, d, a, e? –

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this? Just a custom sort?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use simple order by in postgresql
like this

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
    table (your table name)
ORDER BY
    type ASC, last_submit DESC;
```

Comment: how about sorting like b, c, d, a, e? –

Comment: b, c, d,a,e is not sorted version of the list

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to sort your query using the two columns in order.

Add this part to the end of your query.

```
ORDER BY type, last_submit DESC;
```

Check out this question ["SQL multiple column ordering"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: how about sorting like b, c, d, a, e?

Comment: This is not sorting I did not see a connection in this sorting; This is an arbitrary result unless you have another relation between them that could result in such an order

Answer (score 0):

This code should get you your desired output.

```
SELECT 
     customer_ID,
     Name,
     Type,
     Last_Submit
FROM 
     [schema name].[your table name]
ORDER BY 
     Type ASC, Last_Submit DESC
```